# How can I obtain the braces shown in the below picture?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I am in need to input a certain type of braces to my report and I am not able to find it in latex. Can Somebody help me with this?. I have included a picture of it. Have alook at it.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try double square bracket `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` from `\usepackage{stmaryrd}`

`\llbracket x \rrbracket`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @A K Tom Thomas good to know and may be you can accept one of the answers :)

Answer (score 2):

You also can use `\ldbrack` and `\rdbrack` from `mathabx`, which match nicely the default  `Computer Modern` or `Latin Modern`  fonts. The code below shows how to use them without replacing all maths fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{ <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8>
matha7 <8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9 <10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
%
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8>
mathx7 <8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9 <10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\ldbrack} {4}{matha}{"76}{mathx}{"30}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rdbrack} {5}{matha}{"77}{mathx}{"38}

\begin{document}

    \[ \bigl\ldbrack\dot x \bigr\rdbrack = \text{some equation} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This  being said,  other math fonts have defined such delimiters:

- `MnSymbol`, under the names of `\lsem` + `\rsem`,
- `fourier` has `\llbrack`+`\rrbrack`,
- `fdsymbol` and `stix` have `\lBrack`+`\rBrack`,

and possibly  some more which I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

When facing such a problem I mostly look at:

[The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

or at

[detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) - LaTeX handwritten symbol recognition,

For example, you can get the symbol in textmode by:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\textlbrackdbl
```

or in mathmode:

```
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\llbracket
```